# Cassandra user maintained CF indexes

Tags: java, cassandra

Heres a glimpse of a POJO I want to have as a standard column family in 
Cassandra:

```
class Person {
string key
string name
string dob
List<String> phones
List<String> ids }
```

obviously my key is my primary index.
Not sure How to do the Lists? have to create a new CF for them, or add them all as columns?
OK, so I also want everything searchable via equality.
get Person where phone= 1112223333
get Person where firstname=Al and dob=yyyy-mm-dd

I'm talking about 100million Persons, with all columns mostly unique
So does that rule out the builtin Secondary Index?

I "get" having my own CF as an index, where Primary key is the phone and column names are the primary key into Person CF.

But If I need to delete a phone, given key=1234, how do I maintain the CF Index for phones.
TIA Jurgyman

Comment: How many phone numbers do you recon per Person? Is there a one-to-one mapping between phone number and Person or can it be that a phone number belongs to more than one person?

Comment: many to many on phone numbers... husband and wife both list same as home number.

Comment: One idea is to store the phone numbers as a JSON String in the phone column in Person CF. When removing a phone number you query the row with given key e.g. 1234 removing the entry in the phone column and removing the corresponding row in the index CF.

Comment: why json? Its just a list.why not just use delim and split.  Also, have another list attrib from 1 to 10k values. But avg vals is just 4.  Ive seen others suggest putting it al in col name. Phone:1115551212 - , ....

Comment: The format isn't important, you can of course put it in the format of your choice. If you have an List attribute which might contain 10k of values I guess it's better to store the values in column name as suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, secondary indexes are not going to be the right choice, because they work well in cases where you have low cardinality (i.e. a lot of repeating values).  Phone numbers don't satisfy this.  They will technically work, but will be inefficient as your cluster size grows.

You are correct that if you need a two-way lookup without secondary indexes, probably the best approach is to maintain your own index.  This follows the general design philosophy of writing your data the way you need to read it.  Coming from an RDBMS world this can take some getting used to, as you're accustomed to normalization.

I think the piece you're missing is that you'll want to store the phone number in BOTH places--your person CF and the index.  This will allow you to look at phones for people and people for phones.  When you need to add/remove phones, you'll do it in both places simultaneously.  You're just moving the logic that keeps the relationship from the DBMS to your application.

Comment: Ive seen examples of people putting the "data" as the column name... especially in the "index" type of CFs.  Is there a gain in doing that? (perhaps IO, no getValue call).  If one of my List<string> attributes could get upto 10k... should I NOT add them all as columns... and perhaps put 10 or 100 in the value, and have column names like this:  attr_10  attr_20 attr_30 (where 10 delimmted values are in the value field).

Comment: @AlanJurgensen that's been a popular approach in Cassandra models since Cassandra has been around. But with Cassandra 1.1, there are additions to the CQL language which make working with that sort of "transposed" or "sideways" data model lots easier. See http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/schema-in-cassandra-1-1 for a good introduction and explanation of how a composite key may be perfect for what you need.